# PHP: Improve extends mechanism to follow rules?

Tags: php

Lets say I have a class called Controller, which call controller classes use.

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Controllers;

class Controller {

}
```

I have a few classes like this, imagine their in separate files.

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\Template;
use App\Providers\Configuration;

class LandingController extends Controller {

    private $template;

    public function __construct(Template $template, Configuration $config) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}

class SomeOtherController extends Controller {

    private $template;

    public function __construct(Template $template, Configuration $config) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

Now, all these classes are controllers. They always get passed the same parameters via constructor, and all have the same `use` statements. Is there some way to force it to follow these rules?

Do I really need to include all 3 use statements in every controller file?

Answer (score 3):

Those use statements help you keeping your code clean by moving those classes into an accessible way of current namespace without having to use the full path.

This is what it would look like without use statements.

```
namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;
class SomeOtherController extends \App\Controllers\Controller {

    private $template;

    public function __construct(\App\Providers\Template $template, \App\Providers\Configuration $config) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

If you don't need compile time safety you can skip the use statements and just use variable names.

```
namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;
class SomeOtherController extends \App\Controllers\Controller 
{

    private $template;

    public function __construct($template, $config) 
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

If you just want editor autocomplete you can also use phpdoc comments.

```
namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;
class SomeOtherController extends \App\Controllers\Controller
{
    /**
     * @var $template \App\Providers\Template
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * @param $template \App\Providers\Template
     * @param $config \App\Providers\Configuration
     */
    public function __construct($template, $config) 
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to use use statements you could also use a class alias system to make shortcodes for yourself, saving you having to remember the namespace.
Just put this somewhere after your autoload script at the startup of your application.

```
class_alias('App\Controllers\Controller','Controller',true);
class_alias('App\Providers\Template','Template',true);
class_alias('App\Providers\Configuration','Configuration',true);
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;
use Controller;
use Template;
use Configuration;

class SomeOtherController extends Controller 
{

    private $template;

    public function __construct(Template $template, Configuration $config) 
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }
}
```

Personally i'd recommend you keep on going the way you were with the use statements. It will help you later(read months or years) to find your way back, moving to those classes to check something, and it will provide compile time safety, preventing rogue objects of the wrong type to be passed when for example the wrong class was selected in the editor autocomplete, helping you to catch errors quickly.

In addition I'd suggest adding the phpdoc comments to your variables and methods. It helps when hovering over the methods and variables from other code seeing immediately what types are expected, what is returned and what it will do.

So my recommendation is, add more, not less.

```
namespace App\Controllers\Frontend;
use App\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\Template;
use App\Providers\Configuration;

/**
   * SomeOtherController
   * Handles other stuff than someController.
   * 
   * @package    App\Controllers\
   * @subpackage Frontend
   * @author     a5266680 <example@example.com>
   */
class SomeOtherController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @var $template \App\Providers\Template
     */
    private $template;

     /**
     * @var $configuation App\Providers\Configuration
     */
    private $configuation;

    /**
     * @param $template \App\Providers\Template
     * @param $configuation \App\Providers\Configuration
     */
    public function __construct(Template $template,Configuration $configuation) 
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->configuration = $config;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, I've going back on all my code to document the import parts.

Comment: @a5266680 Remember, if you have something like opcache php will just keep the optimised opcodes in memory having discarded all the comments and stuff. Make your own (future) life easier and document stuff and use imports. It will help you tracing things in the future, adds safety and is helpful if someone else is trying to help you with an issue.